# Why are the args for my storybook component showing as optional instead of required?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have a simple loader component

```js
import React from "react";
import { Backdrop, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export interface LoaderProps {
  open: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  backdrop: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    color: "#fff",
  },
}));

const Loader: React.FC<LoaderProps> = ({ open }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={open}>
      <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
    </Backdrop>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

Here is the story for it:

```js
import React from "react";
import Loader, { LoaderProps } from "./Loader";
import { Story } from "@storybook/react/types-6-0";

export default {
  title: "Loader",
  component: Loader,
  excludeStories: /.*Data$/,
};

export const loader: Story<LoaderProps> = (args) => <Loader {...args} />;
loader.args = {
  open: true,
};
```

When I hover over open in the args it says the type could be `boolean | undefined` instead of just `boolean`? Why is this when the LoaderProps should enforce that is of type `boolean`?

Comment: As a fast (just fast, not reliable, not flexible, just fast) solution - use https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package and remove Partial from the Storybook types.
node_modules/@storybook/addons/dist/types.d.ts
line number 120

Comment: hi @spamspark, you can config it on `main.js/ts` and you can add `shouldRemoveUndefinedFromOptional: true` in `reactDocgen` config.

Answer (score 6):

Checking the `Story` type, it's defined as `BaseStory<Args, StoryFnReactReturnType> & Annotations<Args, StoryFnReactReturnType>`.

`BaseStory` isn't particularly interesting or relevant here, but `Annotations` has the property: `args?: Partial<Args>`.

In your code, `Args` is `LoaderProps`, so the `Annotations` object has an optional property `args` that itself is all of the `LoaderProps` properties made optional. That is, `loader.args` is of type `Partial<LoaderProps>` which is `{ open?: boolean }`. The fact that it is optional is what allows it to also be `undefined`.

As for *why* storybook does this, I can only guess since the documentation in the types on `Annotation.args` in the type definitions has a dead link. If the properties on `args` were required, then you would *have* to set *all* of the properties in your `Props` definitions.